# What are the ~>=~ and ~<~ operators in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

My query's filter was `school ~ '^nebraska'` and this was the resulting query plan. What is `~>=~` and `~<~`? These appear to be ungoogleable and I can't find them in the PostgreSQL docs.

```
->  Nested Loop
        ->  Index Scan using schools_school_712ef684_like on schools u2
            Index Cond: (((school)::text ~>=~ 'nebraska'::text) AND ((school)::text ~<~ 'nebraskb'::text))
            Filter: ((school)::text ~ '^nebraska'::text)
```

The `schools_school_712ef684_like` index is a `btree (school varchar_pattern_ops)` created by Django automatically.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807872/operator-in-postgres) is your answer. Next time you search, put special characters in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
select opcname, amopstrategy,amopopr::regoperator
from pg_am am
join pg_opfamily opf on am.oid =opf.opfmethod
join pg_opclass opc on opf.oid = opc.opcfamily
join pg_amop amop  on opc.opcfamily = amop.amopfamily
where amname = 'btree'
and opcname in ('text_ops', 'text_pattern_ops')
and amoplefttype = 'text'::regtype
and amoprighttype = 'text'::regtype
order by 1,2;
```

return

```
/*
    opcname      | amopstrategy |     amopopr
------------------+--------------+-----------------
 text_ops         |            1 | <(text,text)
 text_ops         |            2 | <=(text,text)
 text_ops         |            3 | =(text,text)
 text_ops         |            4 | >=(text,text)
 text_ops         |            5 | >(text,text)
 text_pattern_ops |            1 | ~<~(text,text)
 text_pattern_ops |            2 | ~<=~(text,text)
 text_pattern_ops |            3 | =(text,text)
 text_pattern_ops |            4 | ~>=~(text,text)
 text_pattern_ops |            5 | ~>~(text,text)
 */
```

Then link:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-opclass.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-opclass.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-amop.html

I hope my understand is correct.

---

Faster text pattern match need index. Index is access methods. Then we need index access operator classes.->  `pg_opclass` For each opclass_name  there is detail info  -> `pg_amop`

---

exmaple:
`explain (costs off) select * from tickets where passenger_name like 'ELENA%';`
query plan:

```
                                             QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on tickets
   Filter: (passenger_name ~~ 'ELENA%'::text)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tickets_passenger_name_pattern_idx
         Index Cond: ((passenger_name ~>=~ 'ELENA'::text) AND (passenger_name ~<~ 'ELENB'::text))
(4 rows)
```

predicate1 `(passenger_name ~>=~ 'ELENA'::text`
predicate2 `(passenger_name ~<~ 'ELENB'::text)`

predicate1 mean that pattern_string larger equal 'ELENA' means either **ELENA** or **ELENA...**. or **ELENB...** [B can any character larger than A].  three dot mean characters.
predicate2 mean pattern_string smaller than **ELENB**.
match predicate1 and predicate2 is either **ELENA** or **ELENA...**

---

**update**

```
 select amopopr::regoperator, amopstrategy as st, opr.oprcode, obj_description(opr.oid,'pg_operator') as description
     from pg_am am join pg_opclass opc on am.oid = opc.opcmethod
                join pg_amop amop on amopfamily = opc.opcfamily
                join pg_operator opr  on amop.amopopr = opr.oid
where amname = 'btree' and opcname = 'text_pattern_ops'order by 2;
```

return:

```
     amopopr     | st |     oprcode     |      description
-----------------+----+-----------------+-----------------------
 ~<~(text,text)  |  1 | text_pattern_lt | less than
 ~<=~(text,text) |  2 | text_pattern_le | less than or equal
 =(text,text)    |  3 | texteq          | equal
 ~>=~(text,text) |  4 | text_pattern_ge | greater than or equal
 ~>~(text,text)  |  5 | text_pattern_gt | greater than
```

I think the key part is understand tilde operator.

Comment: That doesn't really explain what those operators *are*...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe updated my answer. correct me if i am wrong...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I get the ops description from postgresql!.